# Create a new static page using blogdown with same hugo theme as main site

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I'm using the R package `blogdown` to create a hugo-powered website. Specifically i'm using the gcushen/hugo-academic theme.

The tutorials by @xieyihui and @apreshill have been wonderfully helpful to get started, and adding new posts is clear, but what about a new static page that uses the same theme as the overall site?

I get that it can be as simple as creating a new .md file with

```
+++
date = "2017-08-01"
title = "new_page_test"
type = "pages"
+++

## new page test

stuff
```

My questions are

1. where do I store this file so that it is copied properly to the public folder?
2. how to I link to this new page from another page? I'm not clear on the organization of the final file structure that gets published.

Comment: A post and a page are essentially the same thing. You can still use the RStudio addin "New Post": https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rstudio-ide.html Just edit the filename to whatever location you want to save under `content/`. More about posts vs pages: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/software-info.html

Comment: Got it. Thank you. This also helped me more quickly come to the decision that I *don't* want all my classes in this same repo - I need a different theme for them. But there are pages (like data) that will be used across class that I can use this method for.

Comment: It seems you know that you can apply different styles to different pages: https://gohugo.io/content-management/types/

Comment: Thanks for that link @Yihui - my intro to hugo is through Allison's tutorial and your blogdown book. hugo and this type of web/blog creation is new to me. Admittedly i've been skimming and just doing enough to get started. I'm at the point I need to do more reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing this for my classes. You can see the end result [here](https://drewtyre.rbind.io), click on "teaching". You can see the source files [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/rbind/cheap_shots). In particular look under the content/classes folder.

1. Create a folder under content. I called it classes but it can be called anything. Add an `_index.md` file to this folder. I edited `_index.md` from the posts folder so it would automatically create a list of the contents of /classes.
2. This is drop dead easy! The relative link to a page, say `content/yourstuff/yourpage.html` is, wait for it, `yourstuff/yourpage.html`. With an index file in `yourstuff` the relative link is just `yourstuff/`. Follow the same structure to add subdirectories. I was blown away.

Comment: This worked - with the correction that the link from, say, the teaching page is [link text](classes/classnumber/)   

No .html, perhaps as long as there is an _index.md file and a classnumber.md 'landing page' type static page that you want to show (which, is what i wanted)

Comment: Hi @atiretoo, I believe I have a similar (if not, the same) question as Robin but I do not get the solution.. I have gone to your teaching tab but I do not see anything related to this. I have a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234722/using-default-hugo-theme-content-through-netlify-produces-blank-webpage-but-wor . And was wondering if you can provide some pointers?