# Using default Hugo theme content through Netlify produces blank webpage, but works locally. blogdown

Tags: html, rstudio, netlify, hugo, blogdown

I have found the same/similar question to mine here: [Create a new static page using blogdown with same hugo theme as main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470817/create-a-new-static-page-using-blogdown-with-same-hugo-theme-as-main-site?rq=1) but I cannot understand what the solution is as there seems not to be one explicitly, or I just do not grasp it.

I am an absolute beginner. I am testing the procedure to move generated code to netlify to produce a website.

I can put the public/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.html file into public/ folder in github and generate the example site on netlify e.g.:

https://github.com/hjhjonas/blogsite/tree/main/public produces

https://elastic-ptolemy-e2ba86.netlify.app/

However I plan to edit the default theme and use that instead. But the default index.Rmd file that produces the index.html file after i edit the yaml files and content files to use is like this:

https://github.com/hjhjonas/blogsite/blob/main/index.html

and produces a blank page on netfify.

[image]

But if I knit from Rstudio and serve_site() locally, it looks like this image attached, which is correctly what I need.

[image]

What I want to do is edit this original theme/layout and put the generated html into the public folder in github for Netlify to read.

The index.Rmd file that produces this local site is just

```
---
site: blogdown:::blogdown_site
---
```

I previous had a 404 error on netlify and followed these steps to realise that the html is required for Netlify to produce the deploy the page:
https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-i-ve-deployed-my-site-but-i-still-see-page-not-found/125

This is the theme that I would like to use https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/hugo-lodi-theme/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you generated the `public/` folder, but it is not meant to be generated by manually copying or moving any files to it. If you publish a site via Netlify, there is no need to generate the `public/` folder locally at all, because it can be automatically generated on Netlify.

First, delete `index.html` in the root directory, and please do not knit `index.Rmd` again in the future. Second, delete the `public/` folder. After the two deletions, I think your site should appear on Netlify soon. If not, see if `blogdown::check_site()` has any recommendations.

Comment: Hi Yihui, I wish to view using the default content from the theme I have chosen ("lodi theme"). How do I do this? I believe I would need to create a folder like content/post/new_site and create a markdown or rmarkdown file? But how would I exactly replicate what is in the example theme to the serve_site() locally?